# os.path.isdir() returns False even when folder exists

Tags: python, filesystems

I'm currently writing a script which has to check if all specified folders actually exist. 
I found out I have to use os.path.isdir() with absolute paths.

I have the following directory structure:

```
X:\
  pythonscripts\
    files\
      Films\
      Series\
    src\
```

When I open op my python command line and try if the folders actually exist, I get the following:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isdir('X:\pythonscripts\src')
True
>>> os.path.isdir('X:\pythonscripts\files')
False
>>> os.path.isdir('X:\pythonscripts\files\Films')
False
>>> os.path.isdir('X:\pythonscripts\files\Series')
False
```

Which is odd, because when I copy and paste these paths into Windows Explorer, I can access them without problems. I checked permissions and all folders have the same permissions on them. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Escape backslash (`\`)

```
os.path.isdir('X:\\pythonscripts\\src')
```

or use raw string:

```
os.path.isdir(r'X:\pythonscripts\src')
```

---

without escape, you get wrong path:

```
>>> '\f'
'\x0c'
>>> print '\f'

>>> print '\\f'
\f
>>> print r'\f'
\f
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use \, you might want to use the os.path.sep so that your code works on other platforms, then you don't have to escape these either.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using

```
os.path.normpath(your_path)
```

you get rit of frontslash/backslash problemens. (But it can change the meaning, so just know what you are doing. But for normal paths there is no problem)

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath

Works very well :)

Comment: Also if you are switching between different systems always use '/' because with norm path you can translate it to windows but not other wise arround

Comment: Thanks ! to me the only thing that works on multiple os