# Copy only directories in a directory tree using shutil in Python

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to copy a directory tree using `shutil` in Python.

I am doing it like this:

```
shutil.copytree(source,target,False,lambda x,y:[r for r in y if os.path.isfile(r)]);
```

where `source` is the path to the source directory, and `target` is the name for a non-existent directory inside which the copy of `source` is going to occur.

The third argument indicates the treatment of symbolic links.

The last argument, from what I understood in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) should be a function that inputs two parameters and returns a list of file-names that will be excluded from the copy. The first input is the name of the current directory, as `shutil` travels the tree recursively, and the second the list of its contents.

This is why I input a lambda trying to return those elements in the list that are files.

But this is not working. It is copying everything.

Where am I getting confused?

---

What I am trying to do is, if I have

```
source\
  subdir1\
     file11.txt
     file12.txt
  subdir2\
     file21.txt
```

I want to obtain

```
target\
  subdir1\
  subdir2\
```

---

By the way, I guess I would be able to write the copy myself using `walk` or `glob`, but I thought `shutil` would be straightforward to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this make any change?

```
shutil.copytree(source,target,symlinks=False,ignore=ignore_files);

def ignore_files(folder, files):
    return [f for f in files if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, f))]
```

Comment: Adding `ignore = ` didn't change it. It still copied subdirectories and files.

Comment: I see, the list of files needed the full path. Changing `is_dir` by `os.path.isdir` is worked.

Answer (score 1):

Fun to find out, try this:

```
shutil.copytree(source,target,False,lambda x,y:[r for r in y if os.path.isfile(x+os.sep+r)]);
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299949/os-path-isdir-returns-false-even-when-folder-exists) the problem seems to be that `r` is not understood by `isfile` until you have a full path, which I rebuild by adding that `x+os.sep+r`.