# Unable to convert image format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert all my images in a file into jpg format, defined as 'a' but I keep getting error as cannot convert. Any help?

```
   from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
#import imtools
#path = imtools.get_imlist('.')
a = 'K:\wq'
for infile in os.listdir(a):
    outfile = os.path.splitext(infile)[0] + ".jpg"
    if infile != outfile:
        try:
            Image.open(infile).save(outfile)
        except OSError as error:
            print ("cannot convert", infile)
```

error log:
   cannot convert manojcasual.png

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Can you post your full error?

Comment: Please paste error log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [os.path.isdir() returns False even when folder exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299949/os-path-isdir-returns-false-even-when-folder-exists)

Comment: Possible Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python

Comment: C:\Users\manoj\venv\triedmanytimes\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/manoj/PycharmProjects/triedmanytimes/Changingformat.py
cannot convert manojcasual.png

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Catch the error with `except OSError as error:`. Print the error, and edit the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns the name of the files, without the path.

Unless the files are in your current working directory, you must give the complete path to `open` them. You can use `os.path.join()` for that.

Also, note that some sequences like '\n' are parsed as special characters in ordinary strings. This can be a problem on Windows, if any of the escape sequences appears in the path, as in 'C:\new'.
To avoid problems, you should always write your literal paths as raw strings (r'.....') to tell Python not to interpret these sequences.

So, your code should look like:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

a = r'K:\wq'  # notice the r'...'

for infile in os.listdir(a):
    outfile = os.path.splitext(infile)[0] + ".jpg"
    if infile != outfile:
        try:
            Image.open(os.path.join(a, infile)).save(os.path.join(a, outfile))
        except OSError as error:
            print ("cannot convert", infile)
```