# os.path.isdir() returns false to an existing folder

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18299949/7770787) other post but none of the solutions there worked, say I have this folder structure:

```
main.py
src\
  s1\
    dummy.txt
  s2\
    dummy.txt
```

And this code:

```py
import os

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    isdir=os.path.isdir(filename)
    print('%s : %s'%(filename,isdir))
```

When I run it with `.` as the parameter of `listdir()` it works, it shows `src : True` and `main.py : False` which is right because there is a folder called `src` but when I try running it with `src` as parameter this is the output I get: `s2 : False` and `s1 : False`, it should return true because there are also two folders inside src which are called s1 and s2.

I can't really use escaped backslashes as the folder path is going to be provided by other functions so it's all dynamic, but I've tried dynamically replacing the backslashes to forward slashes and it also didn't work.

I created this [Repl](https://repl.it/@DarkCeptor44/ospathlistdir-returns-False-for-existing-subfolders) to show exactly what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because it is checking if `s1` is a directory under the current working directory.

```
>>> for x in os.listdir('src'):
...     print(f'Does {os.path.abspath(x)} exists? {os.path.exists(os.path.abspath(x))}')
...
Does d:\SO\tmp\s1 exists? False
```

So I would suggest to use scandir instead.

```
>>> with os.scandir('src') as it:
...     for entry in it:
...             print(f"{entry} is directory? {os.path.isdir(entry)}")
...
<DirEntry 's1'> is directory? True
```

It is even better if you use `pathlib` module for filesystem related stuff.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> entries = Path.cwd().glob("**/*")
>>> for entry in entries:
...     print(f"{entry} is a directory ? {entry.is_dir()}")
...
d:\SO\tmp\src is a directory ? True
d:\SO\tmp\src\s1 is a directory ? True
```

Comment: I had tried pathlib but not in that way, from what I found I had to use Path('path/to/folder') and then use the is_dir() method, that didn't work but yours does, thank you!